# Get LDAP Information For University Email. For Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, google-workspace, ldap

I am a Student at Northeastern University. They use G-Apps for email ids, so whenever I need to email someone, using university Id which ends with husky.neu.edu. I have to go Gmails compose mail, They have some LDAP Setting by which I get all the email ids using AJAX in 
"To" as soon as I start typing.

I want to configure same in Thunderbird, I contacted university but they are not able to help me. Is it possible that on my G-Apps Gmail Settings those LDAP Parameter needed for configuration are presents?

Can anyone help me? I want to configure a directory reference in my email client thunderbird, I dont know the parameters to use, it is possible I can get it somehow?

Comment: In my situation, I need to extract LDAP parameters from thunderbird, they seem to be hidden by my University.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just need to set up Thunderbird's LDAP address book. For distinguishing the correct ldap server to use, you need to investigate, when university refused to help you. You can try ldap://cluster.ldap.ccs.neu.edu. Connect with ldapsearch or any other tool and try if the server holds the email IDs and what structure is it using for storing.